# Chrome driver auto installation is not working using the module chromedriver_autoinstaller

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

`chromedriver_autoinstaller.install(True)` returns None. It was working from long time and suddenly returns None type. Attached screenshot.

[image]

I tried the following code

```
import chromedriver_autoinstaller as chrome
chromepath=chrome.install(True) # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
# and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
# then add chromedriver to path
# If you pass 'TRUE' parameter then it will download the 
# Chrome driver in Current Working Path

print(chromepath)
```

Comment: Hey, I just resolved this issue by updating chromedriver_autoinstaller module. Problem Solved